# On Subgroups of Same order of Simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

We know that, If there exists none other than only subgroup $H$ of order $m$, then $H$ is normal in $G$. When It comes to simple group, There should exist at the least $2$ subgroups of same order. To generate subgroups of The same order as $H$ consider $gHg^{-1}$ where $g$ is some element in $G\setminus H$.

My question is whether can we generate all the subgroups of the same order in the above manner? i.e. taken a subgroup $K$ of order $m$ is there an element $g$ in $G\setminus H$ such that $gHg^{-1}=K$? at least for the group being simple.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use mathjax, please.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea how to use it. Can you help me in with the question.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/17111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no, and there are many examples.

Consider for example the alternating group $G = A_6$. Let $H$ be a subgroup generated by $3$-cycle, and let $K$ be a subgroup generated by a product of two disjoint $3$-cycles. Then $H \cong K$, but $H$ and $K$ are not conjugate subgroups in $G$. You can easily generalize this to find many more examples.

Comment: You mean by not conjugate, there exists no g in $G-H$ as $gHg^-1 = T$ where H and T got same order. So we can list more subgroups other than the forms $gHg^-1$ ? ( Currently I have no idea of alternating groups or the cycles neither conjugacy) Moreover I am just concerned about simple groups so could you please give an example on that if possible.

Comment: @spin I wish you'd used any other alternating group! The example is fine but of course in this case an outer automorphism will swap the subgroups. And the OP ought to be finding  other examples themself as you suggest and saying that they have no idea about alternating groups and cycles means they are not ready to understand answers to their perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @k.vishal I suggest you work with concrete elements in $S_n$ with $n\le 5$. You can't just know what a simple group is without having some common examples in mind. The facts you need are: any permutation is a product of unique cycles, conjugation does not change cycle types, disjoint cycles commute, the alternating group $A_n$ is the subgroup of the even permutations in $S_n$, $A_n$ is simple for all $n\ge 5$.

Comment: @k.vishal: The alternating groups $A_n$ are simple for all $n \geq 5$, so in particular $G = A_6$ is simple. If you are interested in this question for simple groups and do not know about about alternating groups or permutation groups, I think the other simple groups will not be easier! So I would suggest learning about them first.

Comment: @k.vishal: Yes exactly, subgroups $H$ and $T$ are said to be conjugate if $T = gHg^{-1}$ for some $g \in G$. And yes there are many examples of subgroups of same order which are not conjugate in $G$, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @ancientmathematician,@durianice,@spin Thank you all for the suggestions. I am actually following herstein book of algebra. This question I raised was when I came across a statement that every non-abelian simple finite group has even order. I just wanted to construct a proof of it. In that process I came across a dilemma and now am progressing from your comments.

Comment: @k.vishal The fact that every non-abelian finite simple group has even order is called the Feit-Thompson theorem (or the odd order theorem). The proof is hundreds of pages long and requires extensive background in group theory and representation theory. Basically it is way too difficult for a beginner